# While solving Captcha, Program gets stuck using Flask and Multiprocessing together

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, recaptcha

So I have been playing around with Captcha, Multiprocessing and Flask.

*What have I done so far:*

Basically what I have done is that I have created own Mutltiprocessing where I enter how many tasks/processers I want to run during this script. It will say if I enter 3 then it will give me a process of 3 "threads" which works fine.

Also whenever `webbrowser.open('http://Thrillofit.baller.com:5000/solve')` opens, It works aswell. Also get a captcha that is able to solve.

Basically meaning the captcha does work and also the multiprocessing:

***What's the issue then?***

The issue is sitting now whenever I run the program it gets stuck when solving, basically I can solve how many captchas as I want but it will not continue which I can't get a grip of why? A GIF pic of what is happening: https://i.gyazo.com/d5f183471f20be5eda6be939d255a157.mp4

In the video you can see that i am trying to solve the captcha but nothing happeneds to the program like it gets stuck.

*MY thoughts* is that it might be a issue between Multiprocessing and Captcha/flask but I can't see the issue and I have been completely blind at this point. Maybe there is someone that might see the problem?

The goals is to whenever I solve a captcha, It should print out a token (Inside the `def passwd():` method but nothing prints out and just gets stuck pretty much...

```
import requests, time, json, re, sys, os, timeit, random, multiprocessing, traceback, threading, names, logging, webbrowser, _thread
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

tokens = []

def captureToken(token):
    expiry = datetime.now().timestamp() + 115
    tokenDict = {
        'expiry': expiry,
        'token': token
    }
    tokens.append(tokenDict)
    return


def sendToken():
    while not tokens:
        pass
    token = tokens.pop(0)
    return token['token']


def manageTokens():
    while True:
        for item in tokens:
            if item['expiry'] < datetime.now().timestamp():
                tokens.remove(item)
        time.sleep(5)


app = Flask(__name__)

log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def base():
    return redirect("http://Thrillofit.baller.com:5000/solve", code=302)


@app.route('/solve', methods=['GET'])
def solve():
    sitekey = "6LdyFRkUAAAAAF2YmQ9baZ6ytpVnbVSAymVpTXKi"
    return render_template('index.html', sitekey=sitekey)


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    token = request.form.get('g-recaptcha-response', '')
    captureToken(token)
    return redirect("http://Thrillofit.baller.com:5000/solve", code=302)



def info(thread):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    passwd()


def passwd():
    lilcapttoken = sendToken()
    print(lilcaptoken)


def main():

    webbrowser.open('http://Thrillofit.baller.com:5000/solve')

    user_input = 0
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'How many tasks do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n' + Fore.RESET))
        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED + "Stop being stupid" + Fore.RESET)
            continue
        else:
            HowManyThread = user_input
            print()
            i = 0
            jobs = []
            for i in range(HowManyThread):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=info, args=(str(i),))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(app.run, ())
        _thread.start_new_thread(manageTokens, ())
        main()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(traceback.print_exc())
        print(traceback)
```

Comment: If you're running this via the flask development server - which is single threaded, and then creating threads and expecting things to go smoothly inside a view - it's not :)

Comment: Oh @JonClements, Might I ask how come? Why wouldn't it :)?

Comment: Have a google (or your SE of choice) for using threads inside flask apps... it's err... quite a messy subject to explain :)

Comment: Will do! In the meantime, Do you maybe have a suggestion of what I could do instead? Like a better way than Flask maybe?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - but it looks like a producer-consumer with an externally populated queue of some sort would work? In short - not really :)

Comment: Yeah pretty much that. Could also be a list where I save all Tokens but However the issue sits already where you already said with Flask being singe threaded only. So might find a another solution or maybe someone else have a suggestion for me :)

Comment: There is a `threaded=True` option you can use in `app.run` - not sure it'll play nice though for your use case... Anyway - good luck.